# Evaluate project full path in XAML designer (XDesProc.exe)

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, mvvm, design-time

I have `UserControl` displaying file information. And I want to see test file information in visual studio designer using view-model mock. Here is XAML:

```
<Label Content="{Binding DateCreated}"/>
```

View-model:

```
internal class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel(string pathToFile) 
    {
        var file = new FileInfo(pathToFile);
        this.DateCreated= file.CreationTime.ToShortDateString();
    }

    public string DateCreated{ get; set; }
}
```

In design-time I see real file information in designer using view-model mock class:

```
internal class ViewModelMock : ViewModel
{
    public ViewModelMock() : base(@"D:\Images\mock.png")
    {
    }
}
```

I plug mock into xaml via `d:DataContext` and `d:DesignInstance`:

```
<UserControl ...
    xmlns:mocks="clr-namespace:Company.Product.Mocks"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance mocks:ViewModelMock, DesignTimeCreatable=True}">
```

It works, but the problem is in this `@"D:\Images\mock.png"` **hardcoded value**. As soon as solution powered by TFS, I need to place the image into the project and reference this image from `ViewModelMock`, relative to project path.

How can I do that?

Simple methods like getting current working directory gives '*C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE*', I guess because this is location of XDesProc.exe which responsible for visual studio designer.

Currently I'm using *EnvDTE* method described [in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054182/programmatically-getting-the-current-visual-studio-ide-solution-directory-from-a) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057763/how-do-you-get-the-solution-directory-in-c-sharp-vs-2008-in-code) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176042/envdte-not-found-in-vs2012-works-in-vs2010):

```
var solutionFullName = ((EnvDTE.DTE)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.12.0")).Solution.FullName;
var projectPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(solutionFullName), "ProjectFolderName");
```

But this has almost the same problem - hardcoded "VisualStudio.DTE.12.0" constant (which means Visual Studio 2013), so I'm still trying to find better solution.

Comment: Same problem here in 2020, have you found the solution?

Comment: @hybrid2102 Nope, and I didn't research this problem since, so it would be interesting to know whether situation changed in VS2019, or better hack involved :)