# CodeSmith.Insight.ClientError CodeSmith 5.2

Tags: envdte, codesmith

Can someone help me with this problem?. I have been having with CodeSmith 5.2. Not sure if I messed up something with visual studio..I just right click and manage or Generate  output and this error occurs

If I try to open CodeSmithapplication and debug separately through CodeSmith studio, then it generates the .cs and generated.cs files correctly. Only when it is in the application and I right click to generate outputs, this error occurs.
Why is it complaining about Env_DTE?

This the error I am getting

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<CaseReport xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.codesmithtools.com/insight/v2">
  <MessageSignature i:nil="true" />
  <ProjectId>24</ProjectId>
  <Description i:nil="true" />
  <IsDescriptionHtml>false</IsDescriptionHtml>
  <MessageDate>2016-02-02T16:47:53.7606242-06:00</MessageDate>
  <MessageIdentifier>95e884f0-eb58-42e2-8bcc-e52d23909897</MessageIdentifier>
  <Attachments />
  <CaseType>CrashReport</CaseType>
  <ClientVersion>1.0.0.10642</ClientVersion>
  <CustomFields>
    <CustomField>
      <Key>Platform</Key>
      <Value>Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0, (x64)</Value>
    </CustomField>
    <CustomField>
      <Key>Version</Key>
      <Value>1.0.0.10642</Value>
    </CustomField>
    <CustomField>
      <Key>AssemblyFileVersion</Key>
      <Value>5.2.1.10970</Value>
    </CustomField>
  </CustomFields>
  <ExceptionDetail>
    <Description>System.NotImplementedException: Not implemented (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004001 (E_NOTIMPL))
   at EnvDTE.Document.get_Kind()
   at CodeSmith.VisualStudio.Package.Services.ProjectService.SaveAll()
   at CodeSmith.VisualStudio.Package.Commands.GenerateOutputsCommand.Invoke(Object inArg, IntPtr outArg)</Description>
    <ErrorCode i:nil="true" />
    <ExceptionTypeName>System.NotImplementedException</ExceptionTypeName>
    <ExceptionXml>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?&gt;&lt;object name="NotImplementedException" namespace="System" xmlns="http://schemas.codesmithtools.com/insight/objectdata" /&gt;</ExceptionXml>
    <InnerException i:nil="true" />
    <Message>Not implemented (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004001 (E_NOTIMPL))</Message>
    <MethodName>get_Kind</MethodName>
    <ModuleName>EnvDTE</ModuleName>
    <ModuleVersion>8.0.0.0</ModuleVersion>
    <Source></Source>
    <StackTrace>   at EnvDTE.Document.get_Kind()
   at CodeSmith.VisualStudio.Package.Services.ProjectService.SaveAll()
   at CodeSmith.VisualStudio.Package.Commands.GenerateOutputsCommand.Invoke(Object inArg, IntPtr outArg)</StackTrace>
  </ExceptionDetail>
  <ReportHash>68c99a55f4cd2227874d69af3245f8d575cb31c1</ReportHash>
  <Tags>
    <string>Package</string>
    <string>Package</string>
  </Tags>
  <Title>Not implemented (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004001 (E_NOTIMPL))</Title>
</CaseReport>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EnvDTE not found in VS2012 works in VS2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176042/envdte-not-found-in-vs2012-works-in-vs2010)

Answer (score 0):

I work for CodeSmith. I believe you are using an old version of 5.x and this was probably fixed in 5.3 of Generator. I'd upgrade to that version free of charge and try it. Also, I'd highly recommend upgrading to 7.x as we've completely rewrote most of the components and fixed a TON of bugs and added many new features while being backward compat.